# Problem in solving an Integral.

Tags: integration, fractions

I'm solving a solid of revolution problem and I'm stuck at this point. The u-subtitution doesn´t work, I don´t know what method use.

$\pi\int(\frac{4x-1}{8x^4})^2$

Comment: Expand and integrate term by term.

Comment: It can work, but you have to do it multiply times with multiple variables. Start with $u=4x$

Comment: Is there another way? I don´t really get it. The fact of the square in confuse.

Comment: As André suggested, I'd go for the straightforward way. Expand the square and separate the terms. Then it jut becomes a polynomial integration problem.

Comment: But, if I expand the terms I´ll get factors, and I can´t do anything with that. Sorry If I don´t get it still, I´m beginning with this type of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way that Andre suggest in the comment and the straightforward way:$(4x-1)^2=16x^2-8x+1$, then $ (4x-1)^2/(64x^8)=1/4x^6-1/8x^7+1/64x^8$

Comment: And Do you square the "8x^4"?

Comment: then you have $(4x-1)^2/(64x^8)$

Comment: So...Why Do yo get the 2/x2−1/x3+1/(8x4)?

Comment: I thought the integral is $(4x-1)^2/(8x^4)$, see edit